# Page says 'No data available' even though I am getting user lists in react

Tags: javascript, mern

I am a beginner in MERN stack. I am just stuck at one place and it has been hours I cant solve it.

Issue:

When I press view users button in landing page, it takes me to view page where I want to render user lists. But it says No data available.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCa0n.jpg)

CODE:

Landing Page:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../../src/App.css';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const LandingPage = () => {
    const [alertShown, setAlertShown] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!alertShown) {
            alert("You've successfully logged in!");
            setAlertShown(true);
        }
    }, [alertShown]);


    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleRedirectToView = () => {
        navigate('/view');
    };

    return (
        <div
            style={{
                backgroundImage: 'url("https://milonelawoffice.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/slide3.jpg")',
                width: 1280,
                height: 609,
                backgroundSize: 'cover',
                backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                paddingTop: 80
            }}
        >
            <headingText style={{ fontSize: "40px", textAlign: "center" }}>Welcome to the Dashboard!</headingText>
            <br></br>
            <center>
                <Button onClick={handleRedirectToView} variant="contained" sx={{ backgroundColor: '#C1C8EB', color: '#0C142C' }}>View Users</Button>
            </center>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LandingPage;
```

View page:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import '../../src/App.css';

const View = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("http://localhost:4000/getUser", {
        method: "GET",
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.data);
      });
    },[]);

    return(
        <div>
            {data && data.length > 0 ? (
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Password</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {data.map(i => (
                            <tr key={i.email}>
                                <td>{i.email}</td>
                                <td>{i.password}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            ) : (
                <p>No data available</p>
            )}
        </div>
    )

};

export default View;
```

I tried to get list of users.

I was expecting it to be rendered on screen.

But all I got was lists of users showing as array in JSON inside console of browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to console `data`, i think that the state `data` is not set properly.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://localhost:4000/getUser") //there is no need for setting the method in this case because it's by default Get.
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    setData(data); //just the array of users
  });
},[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can try to help you with one question and two tips:

Q: Are you sure that data.data exists? `setData(data.data);` This should be the response structure if I'm not wrong:

```
data: {
  data: {}
}
```

Maybe that's what's breaking your code.

Tips:

1. Use **console.log(data)** so you can check if data is being stored on state. (Should be before return() and after useEffect)
2. Create a helper file with fetch method applying **try catch**.
   Here you'll find some examples and more information about it.
   https://ilikekillnerds.com/2023/02/handling-errors-with-the-fetch-api/